# Creating a subelement of xml the right way using linq to xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My problem is that the store name should be the sub element of company name but what happen is that they are the same in line How can I fix this?

Here is the sample output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records>
  <CompanyName>Company 1</CompanyName>
  <StoreName>Store 2</StoreName>
  <StoreName>Store 3</StoreName>
  <StoreName>Store 5</StoreName>
  <CompanyName>Company 2</CompanyName>
  <StoreName>Store 1</StoreName>
  <StoreName>Store 4</StoreName>
</Records>
```

Here is my code:

```
qlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select company_name, company_id from company", cn);
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.company.company_name, dbo.store.store_name, dbo.store.company_id FROM dbo.company INNER JOIN dbo.store ON dbo.company.company_id = dbo.store.company_id", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select store_name, company_id from store", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            adapter2.Fill(dt2);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            XElement xml = new XElement("Records");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                xml.Add(new XElement("CompanyName", row["company_name"].ToString()));
                foreach (DataRow row1 in dt2.Rows)
                {
                    if(row["company_id"].ToString() == row1["company_id"].ToString())
                    {
                        xml.Add(new XElement("StoreName", row1["store_name"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }

            xml.Save("C:\\Users\\PHWS13\\Desktop\\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the element to `xml` which is always at the same level (i.e. you are always adding elements as children of your "Records" element).

Try this:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Records");
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var companyName = new XElement("CompanyName", row["company_name"].ToString())
    xml.Add(companyName);
    foreach (DataRow row1 in dt2.Rows)
    {
        if(row["company_id"].ToString() == row1["company_id"].ToString())
        {
            companyName.Add(new XElement("StoreName", row1["store_name"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```